# LibGDX variable accessed from within inner class

Tags: java, libgdx, boolean, listener, final

I want to make a method(addButton) that would all what's now done by the constructor, but taking some variables. Now i'm stuck cause there is an error which says that I need to make the boolean final, but I don't want to do that. How should I go about this?

Here is the code:

```
    public void addButton(Table table,String key,boolean bool){

        atlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/buttons.pack"));
        skin=new Skin(atlas);
        buttonStyle.up=skin.getDrawable(key+".up");
        buttonStyle.down=skin.getDrawable(key+".down");

        button=new Button(buttonStyle);
        button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                bool=true; //this boolean
                return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                bool=false; //and this
                super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            }
        });
        table1.add(button);

    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with making it `final`? Many people do that even without being "forced" to do so. Furthermore, please post only the relevant code...

Comment: Making it final will make it unchangable, or am I wrong?

Comment: The way you are doing it doesn't work anyway, you are not changing anything that way. You should read about how paramaters in Java work.

Comment: Could you suggest something that would do the job?

Comment: You could wrap that boolean in another class, make that final and then change the boolean field of it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. If you just want to know if the button is pressed or not, you can use [`Button.isPressed()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html#isPressed--), because `Button` already keeps track of that.

If you want to do something else, you would be better off creating your own `MyButton` which `extends Button`. `MyButton` could have a field `private boolean bool` and add that `ClickListener` in the constructor. This click listener will then be able to access the field of the button via `MyButton.this.bool` and can change it.

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

private boolean bool;

public MyButton(...) {

    addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            MyButton.this.bool=true;
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            MyButton.this.bool=false;
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Another solution would be to keep your current setup, but wrap the primitive value in another class:

```
public class DataWrapper {
    public boolean bool;
}

public void addButton(Table table,String key, final DataWrapper data) {
    ...

    button=new Button(buttonStyle);
    button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            data.bool=true;
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            data.bool=false;
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
    });
    table1.add(button);
}
```

Comment: But will this work, cause I want that method so I can easily create new buttons?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Ok I found another solution :) Instead of the boolean I passed in a Button and from another class just tested buttonName.isPressed();